# Count recurring values without counting the first one as recurring

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a true/false indicator, whether the value has already appeared before. However, the first value within the same month should not be flagged as TRUE but as false.

E.g. in the sample below, the first 1@a.com in April should be false, but the second one should be true, as well as the 1@a.com in May. I'm getting a bit confused on how to use the COUNTIF formula properly. The end product should be whether a customer has already booked before, either in the same month or any month before....

Thanks for your time and your help!

[image: sample]

Comment: It would make it easier, if you could transform you data into 2 columns, "Months" and "Emails".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data starts in A2: `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1`

Comment: That won't work as intended, I'm afraid, as it would give A2 a TRUE value where it should be false. Within the same month, the first occurrence should always be FALSE, and the second occurence onwards should be TRUE

Comment: Updated with an extra condition

Comment: @user2857795 - after messing around even more, that should do the trick

Comment: Hm, for some reason that does not work for me. The use case would be to have a list of all e-mail adresses and check it against the existing email adresses, whether it already exists or not. This should be independent of the position of the text and thus your code wouldn't really work :/

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the formula from B3 in error.  Edited yet again, hopefully for the last time.  If this is not what you are looking for, could you please include some sample data with the values the formula should be returning?